# c# decimal object.ToString() replaces decimal point by space

Tags: c#, casting

Happened recently (dont know why...)

Now when I converting object {decimal} to string - decimal point is being replaced by space...

so eg 83.62 -> "83 62" why that ??

My method expects object type param, conversion is being done by:
string res =  objString.ToString() ;

Comment: version of framework .NET ?

Comment: Which `CultureInfo` do you have?

Comment: Please post a code snippet that reflects you actual code. somehow "objString" doesn't look like it would be of type `Decimal`. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It should be due to the culture set. In some of the Arabic cultures, thin space is used for the decimal separators.

Meanwhile, irrespective of current culture, we can overloaded ToString function to get the desired result.

```
    string dotValue = Convert.ToDecimal(objString).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi Rishu - thanks for tip - but I dont have overloaded ToString() method
VS says only 1 version with any params is allowed

(.NET 4.6.1)

Comment: Hi Maciej, hope you are doing well. Here, we need to convert object to decimal first. Convert.ToDecimal(objString).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: but my function is general - should convert any type to string. Now it seems I have to check what is the type behind and do separate conversion for decimal, int etc. This is a bit overhead as to me...

Comment: In this case, we should check the culture and set it as per our requirement. We can set it to invariantculture also, if it fits the requirement. Although it is also a overhead but in this way your code will be generic.